# How to prove non-integrability of PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, integrable-systems

Given a certain PDE, we have some well-known methods for proving integrability. For example, if we have a Hamiltonian system and 'sufficiently many' first integrals, we can reduce the system to quadratures. In the infinite dimensional case it is a little more complicated, but similar techniques exist, even if they are more difficult to put into practice.

On the other hand, how would one go about showing that a PDE is not integrable? What techniques are available to us?

Comment: Is the heat equation $u_t=u_{xx}$ integrable?  It cannot be reduced to quadratures, but we can find a solution using a Green's kernel.

Comment: I hope my point is generally clear despite vague language. I am interested in integrability and non-integrability.

Comment: I'm not expert enough to write a good answer, but there's the Painlevé test, computing the Lie symmetries, and other metods... Googling “integrability tests differential equations” will give you plenty of links to articles and books.